# Мерцающая графика в Visual C++

Tags: графика, c++

Вывожу в widows form графические объекты. Проблема в том, что после перерисовки эти объекты мерцают, также мерцают при анимации объектов. Я понимаю, почему это происходит, большой объем объектов выводится за определенне время. Подскажите пожалуйсто, как избежать мецание, может можно с начала загрузить всю графику в память, а потом вывести на экран?

Comment: Используйте двойную буфферизацию.

Comment: дело не в том, много или мало Вы рисуете. Дело в том, что Вы рисуете когда Вы хотите, а не когда этого ожидает система. Но в большинстве случаев это решается либо рисованием в OnPaint (или эквивалентах), или, иногда, включением двойной буферизации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включить Doublebuffer на контроле